# Sublime Text 2: Command To Rearrange Tab In Tab Group

Tags: sublimetext2

Does anyone know a default or a custom Sublime command that would rearrange the position of a tab in Sublime Text 2 to avoid dragging and dropping tabs with the mouse.

For example:

While on the last tab in a sublime window the command:

`key + key + 1`

Would move the current tab to the front of the tab group.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[MoveTab](https://github.com/SublimeText/MoveTab) is a pretty awesome plugin.

**Installation**

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd>

*Install Package*

*MoveTab*

**Keybindings**

*Windows + Linux*

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up</kbd> or <kbd>Page Down</kbd>

*Mac*

<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd> or <kbd>Down</kbd>

Comment: This is perfect.